# How to send headers for form data

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to login into Gamestop(gamestop.ca) but it wont let me as shown below. I've tried adding various headers but no luck :(..
I'm just wondering maybe I am adding data incorrectly when sending my post request.. Can someone confirm?
The content type of the website in the response section under network is:

content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8

```
import requests
import json

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {
    'UserName': '*****',
    'Password': '******',
    'RememberMe': 'false'
}
with requests.session() as s:
    r = s.post('https://www.gamestop.ca/Account/LogOn', headers=headers, data=payload)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.content)
print(r.text)
```

```
403
b'<HTML><HEAD>\n<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>\n</HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>Access Denied</H1>\n \nYou don\'t have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;gamestop&#46;ca&#47;Account&#47;LogOn" on this server.<P>\nReference&#32;&#35;18&#46;70fd017&#46;1635453520&#46;211da9c5\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n'
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;gamestop&#46;ca&#47;Account&#47;LogOn" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;70fd017&#46;1635453520&#46;211da9c5
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

p.s. I can login with selenium so I don't think the error is caused by bot protection.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `www.gamestop.ca` has IP restriction so not much people can help you here. Anyways, I ran my VPN and tried to implement your code in Postman. It's getting the same error as yours, I think the odd is true, they seem to have bot protection. Since you said selenium is fine, then just use it.